# How to sort WP_Query by a custom text field (written as a date dd/mm/yyyy)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, loop, date

I have an ACF text field for a CPT that is holding a date in DD/MM/YYYY format (it's a text field and not a datepicker field as the data was imported from a CSV file).

My Wordpress loop then sorts by this field in DESC order but of course as it stands this means it displays the entries for the 31st of the month first as the day is the first part of the string. Is there any way to convert this field on-the-fly so it reads YYYY/MM/DD before being parsed by the loop?

I know how to output the date in the format I want in the front-end:

```
$date = the_field('date'); // eg. 15/05/2020
$orgD = substr($date, 0, 2);
$orgM = substr($date, 3, 2);
$orgY = substr($date, 6, 4);
$newFormat = $orgY . $orgM . $orgD;
$newDate = date("Y/m/d", strtotime($newFormat)); // eg. 2020/05/15
```

But I'm sure that doesn't help in any way for this purpose.

Is there a function I can add that will convert it or create a new custom field in the alternative format?

Comment: `strtotime()` makes assumptions about your date.  A simple change to your date format, replacing the forward slashes with hyphens will enable PHP to correct decode your date string into a timestamp for sorting.  `strtotime( '28-02-2022' )` will return 1646024400

Comment: See the first user comment in the PHP docs here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: @jdm2112 but then how would you convert the date format on-the-fly and then use with the WP_Query?

Comment: A Unix timestamp can be output in any valid date/time format. The PHP function `date()` will accomplish this.  Pass it your preferred format and the timestamp.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php